# SQL Server trigger after insert error all data insert null

Tags: sql-server, datagridview

I need help for trigger after insert, I insert all of data form datagridview I want fill late column with on duty - clock in , but after I created this trigger

```
create trigger insertlate 
on kkpsurabaya
after insert
as
begin
    declare @insertlate varchar(50)
    set @insertlate = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, clock_in ,on_duty) AS MinuteDiff
                       FROM kkpsurabaya)

    insert into kkpsurabaya(Late) 
    values(@insertlate)
end
```

[all data insert null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9eGL.png)

Comment: what your `insertlate` suppose to do ? It seems that you are inserting another rows to the table `kkpsurabaya`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you current trigger are inserting additional rows to the tables. Looks like you want to use trigger to update the `Late` column. In that case, your trigger should be using the `inserted` table join to the base table and update directly

```
create trigger insertlate on kkpsurabaya
after insert
as
begin
    UPDATE     k
    SET        Late = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, i.clock_in, i.on_duty)
    FROM       inserted i
    INNER JOIN kkpsurabaya k
    ON         i.pk = k.pk
end
```

alternatively you can create the `Late` column as a computed column.

Comment: this im only use 1 table i want that late column auto fill afther im insert clock in and on duty.

Comment: that no work, just miss klik. i mean i want trigger in same table i insert.